# Between "to" and "for" , which one is correct in the following quotations

Tags: grammar

It makes problems **for** our society.
and
It makes problems **to** our society.

I think that "for" is only used for positive things.

Comment: "to" is definitely wrong in this case.  Have you considered "in"?

Comment: Also, *for* has nothing to do with positive or negative- so try to forget that notion.

Comment: @Jim, OP is probably thinking of phrases like "I'm for Nixon in '68".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute a word for *makes*. It *creates* problems for our society. It *adds* problems to our society. The preposition, for, precedes period of time, schedule, agreement, person helped, or motive/reason (noun) The preposition, to, precedes destination, distance, comparison, gift recipient, or motive/reason (verb). Check this link: [www.espressoenglish.net](http://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-to-and-for/)